# Is there a way to know if all chunks loaded when using React.Lazy?

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting

I need to add an event listener to all the inputs inside a form. This can be easily done, but the problem is that I have code-splitting enabled. So, when I add the event listener some chunks are not loaded, so, some react components won't get the event listener attached.

Is there a way to know if all chunks loaded when using React.Lazy?

Thanks

Comment: It is hard to guess how you split and structure your code without example. But as far as I know, there are no callback of lazy(). Maybe you could move the event listener down to the respective components or you can add a callback from each lazy loaded components to the parent to collect the signal of if the components is loaded

Comment: Okay, thanks. Maybe I will need to change my approach. Thanks